# API call executed only one time using RxSwift

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, rx-swift

I have this code with seems to be correct. But it's only react on first search change. So the code is executed only one time. I tried to add `concat(Observable.never())` to my getAl function but it still running only one time. Did I miss something ?

```
exists = search.asObservable()
.throttle(0.3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
.distinctUntilChanged()
.flatMapLatest { searchString -> Observable<Bool> in
    guard !searchString.isEmpty else {
        return Observable.empty()
    }
    return ServiceProvider.food.getAll(whereFoodName: searchString)
        .flatMap({ (result) -> Observable<Bool> in
            return Observable.just(result.count > 0)
        })
}
```

Comment: what is `search` ?

Comment: @ULazdins A  Variable<String>

Answer (score 0):

Your code just return an `Observable`. To work with it you should observe it (or rather `subscribe` to it in Rx terminology)

You'll probably want something like this:

```
search.asObservable()
.throttle(0.3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
.distinctUntilChanged()
.subscribe(onNext: { searchString in 
  let exists = ServiceProvider.food.getAll(whereFoodName: searchString).count > 0
  print("Exists: \(exists)")
  // Or do whatever you want with `exists` constant
  // You could call a method to update UI
  if exists {
    self.button.enabled = true
  }
})
.disposed(by: disposeBag) //disposeBag should be your property which will be deallocated on deinit
```